# How to return a model list attribute when button click?

Tags: javascript, jsp, model

```
<div class="row" align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="index" id="index" value="0">
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="tag with-color">
            <div>
                <label id="label"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="next" class="btn btn-primary" value="NEXT" onclick="nextValue()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        var index = document.getElementById("index").value;
        return "${wordList[index+1].word}";
    }
    function nextValue() {
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = getValue();
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "${wordList[0].word}";
    }
```

I have a button and I want to show attribute of list model when I click button.
But I can't use "${wordList[index].word}". How can I fix it?

Comment: Please share the HTML code you are using with this function.

Comment: Could you explain the scenario a bit more. In this case I your getValue() will just return the string value ${wordList[0].word}.
From the current context I would say you have to change it to:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        return wordList[0].word;
    }
</script>`

Comment: <input type="submit" name="next" value="NEXT" onclick="getValue()"/> I want to use ${wordList[index].word}, but it gives error.

Comment: Please share the html.

Comment: I shared the html.